# php update value of array with same key

Tags: php

How can I update same array key with new value

```
Array ( [key1] => 3 [key2] => 2 [key3] => 1  [key4] => 2) 

Array ( [key3] => 6 )
```

Expected answer:

```
Array ( [key1] => 3 [key2] => 2 [key3] => 6  [key4] => 2)
```

Comment: is this your code? need to store them in variables and use  the square brackets(`[ ]`) to access the index values. eg. `$x = array('key1'=>1,'key2'=>2);` `$x['key2'] = 6;`

Comment: just set the value for your key3 in array.
$arrayname['key3'] = 6;

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
$first_array = array('key1' => 3,'key2' => 2,'key3' => 1,'key4' => 2);
$second_array = array('key3' => 6);
foreach ($first_array as $key => $value) {
    if(isset($second_array[$key])) {
        $first_array[$key] = $second_array[$key];
    }
}
var_dump($first_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<?php
$A = array('key1' => 3, 'key2' => 2, 'key3' => 1, 'key4' => 2);
 $B = array('key3' => 6);

 $result=array_merge($A, $B);

print_r($result);
?>
```

Result:`Array ( [key1] => 3 [key2] => 2 [key3] => 6 [key4] => 2 )`

Ref:https://eval.in/391016